# My renderwndow becomes blank and stops working

Tags: c++, sfml

Actually i was trying to make a bullet shooting code.I used vectors and added the sprite into it and the positions in seperate vectors.But when i run my program my window stops working.Here is the code.I hope its not repeated.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#import "bulletcode.h";
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
int main()
{
vector<Sprite> bullets;
vector<float> xp;
vector<float> yp;
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(900, 600), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(75.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
Texture bullet;
bullet.loadFromFile("bullet.png");
shape.setPosition(400,100);
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space)){
        Sprite bulletsp;
        bulletsp.setTexture(bullet);
        bulletsp.setScale(0.8,0.8);
        bullets.push_back(bulletsp);
        xp.push_back(shape.getPosition().x);
        yp.push_back(shape.getPosition().y);
    }
      for(int i=0;i<=bullets.size()-1;i=i){
        yp[i]=yp[i]+0.2;
        i++;
        bullets[i].setPosition(xp[i],yp[i]);
        window.draw(bullets[i]);
     }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#import "bulletcode.h";`? Should that read `#include "bulletcode.h"`?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<=bullets.size()-1;i=i){
                yp[i]=yp[i]+0.2;
                i++;
                bullets[i].setPosition(xp[i],yp[i]);
                window.draw(bullets[i]);
             }
 
      I found that problem is with these line but i dont know whats the problem

Comment: Please *edit your question* instead of adding comments. There's a link just below the tags.

Comment: #include "bulletcode.h"

Comment: i just specified it in following lines

Comment: I am moving sprite in y axis alone

Comment: `;i=i)` is pointless, just write `;)` and make sure that you are incrementing `i` at the point where you _really_ want to (usually after the full loop body), i.e. where `i=i` is now.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing i in the loop.  So on the last iteration, you'll be accessing beyond the ends of the arrays.

You probably want to replace the `i=i` in the loop declaration with `i++`, and not increment i in the loop body.

Comment: Then you have other problems to debug.  ;)  At another quick glance, you'll probably never see your bullets because you're clearing the window after drawing them.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not work because of the for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<=bullets.size()-1;i=i)
```

where `bullets.size()` is a `size_t (unsigned int)`. When your bullets vector is empty (`size() = 0`), the condition `i=0 <= (unsigned int)(0 - 1)` is always true. Your program enters the for body and crashed (yp, xp, bullets are empty).

Your compilers should warn you somewhere about the problem ?

You should use `for(size_t i=0;i < bullets.size(); i++ )` and rework your for body codes, this keeps your code clean and avoid source of problems.